# Getting firebase data in a stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I built an application, which gets data from the firebase (realtime db). I did it whith this code, but I want, that I always get the new data. In the internet I found something like in a stream, but I didn't find a manual for that.

Does somebody know how this works?

This is my code:

```
  void readData() {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('CHECK').once().then(
      (DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
        print(dataSnapShot.value);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code? If it doesn't print any data, are there any error messages showing in the logs of the app?

Comment: no, the code works fine, the only problem I have is that I get the data only once, but I want to get the data for example every 0.5 seconds

Comment: Stream are not made to fetch every n seconds data. Streams are made to "listen" to incoming data as soon as it arrives. Maybe you aren't using correctly firebase api if this doesn't work. Try looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: everything is working, but I get the data only once, because I have the once in my code, but I don´t know what I have to use instead of the once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get the data for example every 0.5 seconds

That's not really how Firebase works. But if you want to get the data from the database once right away, and then whenever it is updated, you can use `onValue` for that.

That'd look something like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('CHECK').onValue.listen((event) {
  print(event.snapshot.value);
});
```

Give it a try: just set up the listener with this code, run the app, and then make a change to the database in the Firebase console. You'll see the data be printed once as soon as you run the app, and then again whenever you make a change.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read in your comments, you want the function to be executed repeatedly every 0.5 seconds.

A stream is not appropriate for that. However, you can use `Timer`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => readData());
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Your `build()` function will be called more than once once `Timer.periodic` is created.

Comment: Does calling ```build()``` method more than once cause the app to be lagy?